# DialogFlow: The number of training phrases exceeds 10

Tags: dialogflow-es

Errors in 'Intent' intent:
The number of training phrases exceeds 10.
com.google.dialogflow.designtime.exceptions.DesigntimeException:  generic::FAILED_PRECONDITION: Errors in 'Intent' intent:
The number of training phrases exceeds 10.

Looks to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#es-agent_1) and found that the limit is 2000. This problem was caused just today, previously 1 year everything was working fine.

Does someone know what the reason is?

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing on this is awkward.

I think it is saying that you should have *at least* 10 training phrases (which is suggested). Tho I haven't seen this as a requirement before.